# Node.js Server become unresponsive after certain time period

Tags: mysql, node.js, nginx

I've recently been having problems with my server which become unresponsive after certain period of time.

Basically after a certain amount of usage & time my node.js app stops responding to requests. I don't even see routes being fired on my console and the HTTP calls from my client (Android app) don't reach the server anymore. But after restart my node.js app server everything starts working again, until things inevitable stop again. The app never crashes, it just stops responding to requests.

I'm not getting any errors, and I've made sure to handle and log all DB connection errors so I'm not sure where to start.

Any clue as to what might be happening and how I can solve this problem?

Here's my stack:

Node.js on Digital Ocean server with Ubutnu 14.04 and Nginx (using Express 4.15.2 + PM2 2.4.6)
Database running MySQL (using node-mysql)

Comment: can you take a look at resource usage such as CPU ? Are you closing all the requests ?

Comment: Check NGINX logfiles.

Comment: @FMashiro 
My server memory uses is from 25-32MB and CPU usage is only 0-2%.
And what is mean by closing all the requests?.

Comment: @robertklep
Nginx show this "SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140A1175:SSL routines:SSL_BYTES_TO_CIPHER_LIST:inappropriate fallback) while SSL handshaking' 
I think this is not the problem.

Comment: @user8051676 Were you able to resolve this problem? I am facing the same issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: same issue here too. everything works fine after restarting